# Find an analytic bijection function ${f(z)}$ on $\Bbb{C}$ such that there exist only one $z_{0}$ such that ${f(z_{0})} = z_{0}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an analytic one-one onto function ${f(z)}$ on $\Bbb{C}$   such that there exist only one $z_{0}$ such that ${f(z_{0})} = z_{0}$.

Comment: All affine functions are 1-1, and most of them have exactly one fixed point.

Comment: @HansEngler could you elaborate your comment for me? explain and teach me please dear sir

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $$f(z)=-z$$Then for $z_0=0$ we have $f(z_0)=z_0$ and for all other $z_1\in \mathbb{C}$ we have $f(z_1)=-z_1\neq z_1$. Similarly the function $$f(z)=\pm i z$$ will work. Even more generally any function $$f(z)=e^{i \alpha} z$$ where $0<\alpha < 2 \pi$ will work where in each case $f(z)=z$ iff $z=0$.

Another class of solutions is
$$f(z)=\beta z$$
where $\beta \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$

Answer (score 2):

Any rotation of the plane that is not the identity map